# Использование другой версии JSON (org.json)

Tags: android, json, зависимости

Добрый день.
В своём приложении я использую самописную библиотеку на Java, использующую зависимость org.json:json:20151123.

В android по умолчанию вшита другая версия.
Вопрос - как можно использовать JSON версии из библиотеки в android проекте? Пробовал в build.gradle прописывать

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.json:json:20151123"
}
```

А также копировал jar в папку libs, но первое породило warnings, которые говорили, что android-json версия важнее, а второе просто не дало собрать apk с ошибкой:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/CDL;
```

Вопрос - как мне использовать в android нужную мне версию org.json?

Comment: т.е. у вас в проекте две одинаковых библиотеке но разных версий?

Comment: Покажите ваши файлы gradle  и  manifest

Comment: В android используется другая версия, а не в конфиге, а конфиг у меня стандартный для всех android-проектов, работающих в AndroidStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389314/3212712) пишут, что у вас не выйдет подменить системную зависимость от к-л либы на собственную.

Скорее всего, если вам принципиально использовать строго определённую версию к-л либы, вшитой в систему, то можно использовать [jarjar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/) для помещения всех классов вашей либы в другой пакет и в коде использовать эти классы из этого пакета. Т.е. сменить импорты по всему проекту.

А вообще совершенно непонятно почему вам нужна именно эта версия либы.

Comment: Дело в том, что в данном случае приложение зависит от либы, а в либе используется JSONObject#keySet(), которого в android-библиотеке нет. Естественно, править либу в данном случае неправильно, поскольку приложение зависит от либы, а не наоборот

Comment: @A.Ovsyannikov, кажется, я не очень понял вашу проблему. Почему бы вам тогда не убрать эту зависимость, использовать системную либу и просто поменять исчезнувший метод на его аналог?

Comment: поменял описание вопроса, посмотрите, может, будет понятней

Comment: @A.Ovsyannikov, боюсь у вас нет выбора и надо править либу

Comment: Пришлось использовать jarjar чтобы org.json "переместить" по пути org.json.newest. Зато теперь всё работает:)